# Failed to sync Gradle project with databinding lib

Tags: android, data-binding, gradle

Recently I'm learning MVP pattern and databinding after the Android Studio being upgraded to ver2.0. And I find a really good sample helping me to understand these.
But as the title I can't gradle  it successfully.
It always gaving a message in the monitor like
    *"Error: Could not  find com.android.databinding:library:1.1.  Required  by: todoapp:app:unspecified"*
the website is https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-databinding
I've done a lot search for this problem but still...

P.S:I also trying to add some code like
`dataBinding {   enabled=true   }`  
 to the other branch which can be sync successfully before...and of course become failed after...
...and the failed message s are similar 
*"Error: failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:library:1.1"*

I can use this databinding part in my own project.
and my AS version is 2.0 ...the .gradle is 2.10

THX A LOT FOR HELPING...

Answer (score 0):

Now I finally can use this project.
I find the point is to change the gradle version in the  `build.gradle` file in  the root .
 It was  likeversion 2.1.0-alpha5  and it cause those problem. After compare with my own project, I change it as 2.0.0 and it's now works well~